# Can I use the [NSArray containsObject:] function on attributes of objects?

Tags: xcode, performance, comparison, nsarray

**Background Information:**

I program an iOS application that contains 2 galleries: A local gallery and a server gallery. When the user updates the server gallery and merges it into his local one, the app should only download the new images.

To minimize memory consumption I save the images and fill the arrays with instances of an `ImageEntity` class with following attributes: ***fileName***, ***filePath*** & ***votingStatus***.

I tried to use following logic to check if the image already exists:

```
for (ImageEntity *imageEntity in self.serverImagesArray) {
  if (![self.localImagesArray containsObject:imageEntity]){
    [self.localImagesArray  addObject:imageEntity];
  }
}
```

**But because each entity is a separate object it will always be added.** Each entity has a unique ***fileName*** though.

---

**Question:**
Can I somehow extend the `[NSArray containsObject:]` function to check if one object in the array has an attribute equal to "someValue"? (When I use Cocoa-Bindings in combination with an ArrayController, I can assign attributes of array elements - I would like to access the attributes similar to this).

---

*I know that I could use compare each entity of the local array to each element on the server array*. **I would have to do O(n^2) comparisons** though and the gallery may contain several hundred images.

**Bonus question:** Am I already doing this without realizing it? Does anybody have details about Apple's implementation of this function? Is there some fancy implementation or are they just iterating over the array comparing every element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I do it is use `valueForKey:` in combination with `containsObject:`. So in your case you should collect all file names of the array and then check if the array contains specific file name you need:

```
NSArray * fileNames = [fileEntityObjects valueForKey:@"fileName"];
BOOL contains = [fileNames containsObject:@"someFilename.jpg"];
```

This would work if `fileName` is property of every object in `fileEntityObjects` array.

**Update**

Yes, you can do this with `NSPredicate` as well:

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.fileName = %@", "someFileName.jpg"];
NSArray * filteredArray = [fileEntityObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Note though that instead of boolean you'd get an array of objects having that filename.

Comment: Every entity must have a fileName because that's the identifier. I'll try this. I'm thinking of creating a NSPredicate to accomplish the same maybe a bit more elegant?

Answer (score 1):

As this question is tagged "performance" I'm adding another answer:

To avoid the n^2 comparisons we have to find a faster way to detect images that are already present. To do this we use a set that can perform lookups very quickly:

```
NSMutableSet *localFileNames = [NSMutableSet set];
for (ImageEntity *imageEntity in self.localImagesArray)
    [localFileNames addObject:imageEntity.fileName];
```

Then we iterate over the server images as before. The previous `containsObject:` is replaced by the fast set lookup:

```
for (ImageEntity *imageEntity in self.serverImagesArray) {
    if ([localFileNames member:imageEntity.fileName] == nil)
        [self.localImagesArray addObject:imageEntity];
}
```